# How to change type from ObservableCollection<object> to ObservableCollection<class> in wpf c#

Tags: c#

I want to create function for generate data to show in treeview.
But have some problem with code below, please help me.

```
//Class for hold all data
public class DataControl
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<object> Data;

    //constructor
    public DataControl(string type, ObservableCollection<object> data)
    {
        Type = type;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

class data model ==============================================

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

class for show Tree View

```
public class ShowTreeView
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataControl> DataStore { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyData> Data { get; set; }

    //Function Show Data In Tree View
    public void ShowData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var obj = new MyData { Id = "0", Name = "Name1" };
            Data.Add(obj);

            //How do i can convert type from ObservableCollection<object> to
            //ObservableCollection<MyData>
            //Please help me.
            // Thank you very much.
            var tree= new DataControl(i.ToString(), Data); //Error code.
            DataStore.Add(tree);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, I want to ask, 
How to create Dynamic function to show data in TreeView control in MVVM?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What do u mean by ObservationCollection<object> and ObservationCollection<class> ???

Comment: Why is your collection using `object` anyway? Use `MyData`.

Comment: because, i want to call it to use anywhere i want.

Comment: I dislike to write code again and again like this. you have any idea for this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Imagine you have this method:

```
void foo(ObservableCollection<object> collection) {
    collection.Add(new Tiger());
}
```

Called in this scenario:

```
var ints = new ObservableCollection<int>();
foo(ints);
```

As you can imagine it's invalid (you're trying to add an object of type `Tiger` to a collection of `Int32`). What you can do is to change `foo()` to accept interface that makes a collection *observable*: `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Your class will then become:

```
public class DataControl {
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public INotifyCollectionChanged Data;

    public DataControl(string type, INotifyCollectionChanged data) {
        Type = type;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

If (in case) you need to modify your collection inside `DataControl` you may simply cast it to proper type (but IMO this will violate `DataControl` contract). Imagine you're observing such collection and you have this handler:

```
void OnObservedCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        AddNewItemsToTreeView(e.NewItems); // NewItems are all "untyped" object
}
```

Comment: Sorry, But you have an idea to create function to show data in treeview in MVVM?